# If value is empty or 0,0 echo something else in php

Tags: php

i code a value for my progress bar in percent. But i need a `if / else` for the case, when supply is "null" and 0,0. Doesn't work so far. Maybe someone can help me out.. what is wrong here. I appreciate it.

```
case 'supplyper':
                    $x = $coin->available_supply;
                    $y = $coin->total_supply;

                $percent = $x/$y;
                $percent_friendly = number_format( $percent * 100, 0 ) . '%'; // change 2 to # of decimals

                if (empty($y)) {
                    $text = '0';
                }
                
                // Evaluates as true because $var is set
                if (isset($y)) {
                    $text = '' . $percent_friendly . '';
                }
```

Comment: If `$y` is 0, `$x/$y` is not allowed because it's a division by zero. You need the check if before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems that $coin->total_supply is a string, first you need to make sure that it can be turn into a valid numeric value. It seems you are using the character ',' as your decimal separator so wee need to replace it with the '.' in order to make it a valid float. So lets try this:

```
$y = str_replace(',', '.', $coin->total_supply);
```

Now we need to make sure $y is a valid float representation:

```
$y = floatval($y);
```

Now check for $y not being zero(0) before you calculate the percentage otherwise you are open to a division by zero error.

You are very close, try this:

```
$x = str_replace(',', '.', $coin->available_supply);
$x = floatval($x);

$y = str_replace(',', '.', $coin->total_supply);
$y = floatval($y);

if (empty($y)) {
    $text = '100%';
} else {
    $percent = $x/$y;
    $percent_friendly = number_format( $percent * 100, 0 ) . '%'; // change 2 to # of decimals
    $text = '' . $percent_friendly . '';
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I tried this. But i still have "inf%" in my result when it is null or 0,0.

Comment: So the value of $y is '0,0' as a string?

Comment: Yes. Think so. I'm a beginner. It is not a array i believe. If i echo $y it is 0,0. In the api it is "total_supply":null.

Comment: That is not a problem, we have all been there. Then you need to make sure you convert the value to its numeric value. Check my edit

Comment: have you changed you post? my result is the same. inf%. hm

Comment: @peer Yes, please check my edit.

Comment: ah ok. thank you very much. can i also add a "100%" for 0 where is now $text = '0'; ?

Comment: But works already. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can. That would mean that when there is no total supply then your text will be 100%. Is that what you are going for?

Comment: yes. this is my last step. but the % will crash my code.

Comment: I edited the code, is that what you meant?

Comment: ah worked. was my fault then. maybe i delete something wrong. thank you!!